# Flutter Invalid Item been shown on Filter

Tags: flutter, listview

Guyz i am facing a big issue.. not sure y is this happening but my function to return a list with filtered records is working correctly.. but still my Listview.builder is showing incorrect items.. i.e. suppose i search for a keyword from my List which has 2 entries.. then the filter Function outcome is correct.. but on Screen Listview Builder is Showing top 2 Items from the original list. not getting y is this happening

```
class DashboardScreenState extends State<DashboardScreen> {
  final ScrollController _scrollController = ScrollController();
  TextEditingController controller = new TextEditingController();
  List<TaskDetails> taskDetailsList = [];
  List<TaskDetails> fullTaskDetailsList = [];

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    taskDetailsList = BlocProvider.of<AppmgrBloc>(context).state.taskDetails;
    if(taskDetailsList.length == 0) {
      InitializerService _initService = InitializerService.instance;
      taskDetailsList = _initService.allTaskList;
    }
    taskDetailsList = taskDetailsList.where((TaskDetails td) {
      if(td.progressStatus == 'COMPLETE' || td.progressStatus == 'DELETE') {
        return false;
      }
      return true;
    }).toList();
    taskDetailsList.sort((td1, td2) => td1.taskBookDate.compareTo(td2.taskBookDate));
    
    print('Init State Size '+taskDetailsList.length.toString());
    fullTaskDetailsList.addAll(taskDetailsList);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print('Build Widget state');
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.grey[200],
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(
          children: [
          getHeaderSearch(),
          /* generateListWithTiles(taskDetailsList), */
          /* taskDetailsList.length != 0 ||  */
          controller.text.isNotEmpty
            ? generateListWithTiles(taskDetailsList)
            : generateListWithTiles(fullTaskDetailsList)
        ]), 
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget getHeaderSearch() {
    return Container(
      color: AppLevelConstants.BASE_BLUE_COLOR,
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(5),
      child: Column(
        children: [
          TaskSearchCustomWidget(
            controller: controller,
            onTextChanged: (textVal) {
              this.searchMethodWithTest(textVal);
            },
          ),
          SizedBox(height: 2,),
          Text('** Press & Hold to Edit All fields..', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 7, color: Colors.white, ),)
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
  
  searchMethodWithTest(String text) {
    taskDetailsList.clear();
    text = text.toLowerCase();
    if (text.isEmpty) {
      taskDetailsList.addAll(fullTaskDetailsList);
      setState(() {});
      return;
    }

    fullTaskDetailsList.forEach((taskdetails) {
      String title = taskdetails.title;
      if (title.toLowerCase().contains(text)) {
        taskDetailsList.add(taskdetails);
      }
    });

    setState(() {});
  }

  ListView generateListWithTiles(List<TaskDetails> tasks) { 
    print('===============================================');
    print(tasks.toString());  /* Filtered list is correct here */
    print('===============================================');
    return ListView.builder(
      scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
      shrinkWrap: true,
      controller: _scrollController,
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(5),
      itemCount: tasks.length,
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        return Card(
          child: DashboardTaskTile(tasks[index]),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the sample app:

[image: Screen Shot]

**Search method:**

```
void searchMethodWithTest(String text) {
    List result = [];
    print("Text: " + text.length.toString());
    if (mycontroller.text.isNotEmpty) {
      fullTaskDetailsList.forEach((element) {
        text = text.trim();
        if (element.toLowerCase().contains(text)) {
          result.add(element);
        }
      });
      print(taskDetailsList.toString());
      setState(() {
        taskDetailsList = result;
      });
      return;
    } else {
      setState(() {
        taskDetailsList = fullTaskDetailsList;
      });
      return;
    }
  }
```

**Full Working Example code:**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  List fullTaskDetailsList = [];
  List taskDetailsList = [];
  TextEditingController mycontroller = TextEditingController();

  void searchMethodWithTest(String text) {
    List result = [];
    print("Text: " + text.length.toString());
    if (mycontroller.text.isNotEmpty) {
      fullTaskDetailsList.forEach((element) {
        text = text.trim();
        if (element.toLowerCase().contains(text)) {
          result.add(element);
        }
      });
      print(taskDetailsList.toString());
      setState(() {
        taskDetailsList = result;
      });
      return;
    } else {
      setState(() {
        taskDetailsList = fullTaskDetailsList;
      });
      return;
    }
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    fullTaskDetailsList = countryList;
    taskDetailsList = fullTaskDetailsList;
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Center(
          child: Column(
            children: [
              TextField(
                controller: mycontroller,
                onChanged: (value) {
                  searchMethodWithTest(mycontroller.text.toLowerCase());
                },
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                  hintText: "Search For Countries",
                ),
              ),
              Text("Searched for: ${mycontroller.text}"),
              Container(
                width: double.infinity,
                height: 400.0,
                child: ListView.builder(
                    itemCount: taskDetailsList.length,
                    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                      return ListTile(
                        title: Text(
                          taskDetailsList[index],
                          style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 20.0,
                          ),
                        ),
                      );
                    }),
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
      // This trailing comma makes auto-formatting nicer for build methods.
    );
  }
}

const countryList = [
  "Afghanistan",
  "Albania",
  "Algeria",
  "American Samoa",
  "Andorra",
  "Angola",
  "Anguilla",
  "Antarctica",
  "Antigua and Barbuda",
  "Argentina",
  "Armenia",
  "Aruba",
  "Australia",
  "Austria",
  "Azerbaijan",
  "Bahamas (the)",
  "Bahrain",
  "Bangladesh",
  "Barbados",
  "Belarus",
  "Belgium",
  "Belize",
  "Benin",
  "Bermuda",
  "Bhutan",
  "Bolivia (Plurinational State of)",
  "Bonaire, Sint Eustatius and Saba",
  "Bosnia and Herzegovina",
  "Botswana",
  "Bouvet Island",
  "Brazil",
  "British Indian Ocean Territory (the)",
  "Brunei Darussalam",
  "Bulgaria",
  "Burkina Faso",
  "Burundi",
  "Cabo Verde",
  "Cambodia",
  "Cameroon",
  "Canada",
  "Cayman Islands (the)",
  "Central African Republic (the)",
  "Chad",
  "Chile",
  "China",
  "Christmas Island",
  "Cocos (Keeling) Islands (the)",
  "Colombia",
  "Comoros (the)",
  "Congo (the Democratic Republic of the)",
  "Congo (the)",
  "Cook Islands (the)",
  "Costa Rica",
  "Croatia",
  "Cuba",
  "Curaçao",
  "Cyprus",
  "Czechia",
  "Côte d'Ivoire",
  "Denmark",
  "Djibouti",
  "Dominica",
  "Dominican Republic (the)",
  "Ecuador",
  "Egypt",
  "El Salvador",
  "Equatorial Guinea",
  "Eritrea",
  "Estonia",
  "Eswatini",
  "Ethiopia",
  "Falkland Islands (the) [Malvinas]",
  "Faroe Islands (the)",
  "Fiji",
  "Finland",
  "France",
  "French Guiana",
  "French Polynesia",
  "French Southern Territories (the)",
  "Gabon",
  "Gambia (the)",
  "Georgia",
  "Germany",
  "Ghana",
  "Gibraltar",
  "Greece",
  "Greenland",
  "Grenada",
  "Guadeloupe",
  "Guam",
  "Guatemala",
  "Guernsey",
  "Guinea",
  "Guinea-Bissau",
  "Guyana",
  "Haiti",
  "Heard Island and McDonald Islands",
  "Holy See (the)",
  "Honduras",
  "Hong Kong",
  "Hungary",
  "Iceland",
  "India",
  "Indonesia",
  "Iran (Islamic Republic of)",
  "Iraq",
  "Ireland",
  "Isle of Man",
  "Israel",
  "Italy",
  "Jamaica",
  "Japan",
  "Jersey",
  "Jordan",
  "Kazakhstan",
  "Kenya",
  "Kiribati",
  "Korea (the Democratic People's Republic of)",
  "Korea (the Republic of)",
  "Kuwait",
  "Kyrgyzstan",
  "Lao People's Democratic Republic (the)",
  "Latvia",
  "Lebanon",
  "Lesotho",
  "Liberia",
  "Libya",
  "Liechtenstein",
  "Lithuania",
  "Luxembourg",
  "Macao",
  "Madagascar",
  "Malawi",
  "Malaysia",
  "Maldives",
  "Mali",
  "Malta",
  "Marshall Islands (the)",
  "Martinique",
  "Mauritania",
  "Mauritius",
  "Mayotte",
  "Mexico",
  "Micronesia (Federated States of)",
  "Moldova (the Republic of)",
  "Monaco",
  "Mongolia",
  "Montenegro",
  "Montserrat",
  "Morocco",
  "Mozambique",
  "Myanmar",
  "Namibia",
  "Nauru",
  "Nepal",
  "Netherlands (the)",
  "New Caledonia",
  "New Zealand",
  "Nicaragua",
  "Niger (the)",
  "Nigeria",
  "Niue",
  "Norfolk Island",
  "Northern Mariana Islands (the)",
  "Norway",
  "Oman",
  "Pakistan",
  "Palau",
  "Palestine, State of",
  "Panama",
  "Papua New Guinea",
  "Paraguay",
  "Peru",
  "Philippines (the)",
  "Pitcairn",
  "Poland",
  "Portugal",
  "Puerto Rico",
  "Qatar",
  "Republic of North Macedonia",
  "Romania",
  "Russian Federation (the)",
  "Rwanda",
  "Réunion",
  "Saint Barthélemy",
  "Saint Helena, Ascension and Tristan da Cunha",
  "Saint Kitts and Nevis",
  "Saint Lucia",
  "Saint Martin (French part)",
  "Saint Pierre and Miquelon",
  "Saint Vincent and the Grenadines",
  "Samoa",
  "San Marino",
  "Sao Tome and Principe",
  "Saudi Arabia",
  "Senegal",
  "Serbia",
  "Seychelles",
  "Sierra Leone",
  "Singapore",
  "Sint Maarten (Dutch part)",
  "Slovakia",
  "Slovenia",
  "Solomon Islands",
  "Somalia",
  "South Africa",
  "South Georgia and the South Sandwich Islands",
  "South Sudan",
  "Spain",
  "Sri Lanka",
  "Sudan (the)",
  "Suriname",
  "Svalbard and Jan Mayen",
  "Sweden",
  "Switzerland",
  "Syrian Arab Republic",
  "Taiwan",
  "Tajikistan",
  "Tanzania, United Republic of",
  "Thailand",
  "Timor-Leste",
  "Togo",
  "Tokelau",
  "Tonga",
  "Trinidad and Tobago",
  "Tunisia",
  "Turkey",
  "Turkmenistan",
  "Turks and Caicos Islands (the)",
  "Tuvalu",
  "Uganda",
  "Ukraine",
  "United Arab Emirates (the)",
  "United Kingdom of Great Britain and Northern Ireland (the)",
  "United States Minor Outlying Islands (the)",
  "United States of America (the)",
  "Uruguay",
  "Uzbekistan",
  "Vanuatu",
  "Venezuela (Bolivarian Republic of)",
  "Viet Nam",
  "Virgin Islands (British)",
  "Virgin Islands (U.S.)",
  "Wallis and Futuna",
  "Western Sahara",
  "Yemen",
  "Zambia",
  "Zimbabwe",
  "Åland Islands"
];
```

Comment: Sorry Brother Results are not getting filtered

Comment: your Answer is correct as i can see my Items are correctly getting filtered but the bigger issue now is .. in Listview.builder when i am using a stateful Expansion Tile that is giving me issues.. i.e it always shows the first item of the list.

Comment: Yes can you try to add a Stateful widget Expansion Tile and Work the filter logic above.. with stateful widget Card as well it always fail.. i.e. if you search for 3rd Item it will show you 1st Item of your list only.